# индексирование ботами

Tags: seo, sitemap

Есть веб приложение, которое полностью переведено на различные языки.
Если пользователь заходит в первый раз, то язык возьмется из заголовков. Все отлично работает, но как заставить гугл и яндекс индексировать ? домен остается одинаковый на всех языках т.е. test.ru (на русском языке) / test.ru (на другом языке). даже сайтмап не поможет. т.к. на всех языках одинаковый url.
поддомены нет желания создавать. есть другие варианты решения этой задачи ?

Comment: В get параметре указывайте язык test.ru/?lang=ru test.ru/?lang=en . Для красоты можно сделать вида test.ru/ru/ test.ru/en/ а на сервере это преобразовывать для выдачи нужного контента(такое можно в .htaccess делать точно)

Comment: Я бы не хотел портить внешний вид урлы. Такую реализацию я знаю. Хотел более современные решение

Comment: А если всегда прописывать к урле ?lang=ru и удалять через js. Так будет индексировать бот ?

Comment: Но с индексирование есть проблема. Переводы загружаются аяксом при открытии страницы (загружаются быстро, но не моментально). Т.е. наполнение любой страницы не заранее заготовленный текст. Как робот отреагирует на это

Answer (score 0):

> на всех языках одинаковый url

Вот и главная ошибка.

В урле должно быть чёткое разделение языков.
Кроме того нужно использовать hreflang.

[Матчасть](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/specialty/international/managing-multi-regional-sites?hl=ru#use-different-urls-for-different-language-versions)

Comment: hreflang используется. Только как робот узнает другие языки ? Язык переключается через js. Смысл просто теряется, если использовать другой урл.

Comment: @GRCR13, Читай написанное выше.